# How to separate Social media application and Game application installed in the device

Tags: java, android-studio

I create project in Android studio to display all application installed in my device, I want to separate the social media application and game application, is it possible? and any hints so i can do it.

Comment: There's no way to tell from a list of apks installed what type of app it is.  You can guess off a few factors, or make whitelists of the names of important games and social media apps.  But there's no way to have a definitive set of all games and all social media apps.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, you should get all installed app package names then you can search package names in the play store to find out their category.

As I know there is no official API by play store so you should search and collect data from HTML and so on. also there should be some third-party APIs, just look for them and probably you will find some of them.

If you want to collect data from the play store, just take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50461981/17219280)

Good luck!